# What do these numbers mean in the exception StackTrace?

Tags: c#, android, exception, xamarin.forms, stack-trace

I have an exception StackTrace and I want to know what do these codes mean for me and my app

Xamarin Exception Stack:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MyProj.Views.Settings.ImportAsXLSX (System.Int32 areaId) [0x00d68] in <c32cefffae994358b5f7974936d47086>:0
  at MyProj.Views.Settings+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<ImportAsXLSX_Clicked>b__1 (System.Object <p0>, System.EventArgs <p1>) [0x0012c] in <c32cefffae994358b5f7974936d47086>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <c623adf6f02045dd95c5158437e90096>:0
  at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in <f6fee5735b27475b877b919201a02731>:0
  at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in <f6fee5735b27475b877b919201a02731>:0
  at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <f6fee5735b27475b877b919201a02731>:0
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.6(intptr,intptr)
```

For example what does this mean?

> [0x00d68] in :0

and how can I even use my previously generated pdb files to find it out?

Comment: https://blog.elmah.io/debugging-system-nullreferenceexception-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object/

Comment: I know it's null reference exception, but I want to know the object causing the error when in release mode, as it doesn't throw this error in normal cases (either it's release or debug)